# Google mini 5.0.4 giving garbage results for Japanese search query in IE

Tags: google-search-appliance

Google mini (v 5.0.4) is giving garbage results for Japanese search query in IE. This works fine in Chrome. How to resolve this?

Comment: This minimal question might earn you downvotes for a perceived lack of effort - can we see a screenshot? In what way is the output "garbage"? Are you running the Google Search Appliance on your premises? Can we see the HTML/CSS that might be responsible?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?